# Slick2D: UnsatisfiedLinkError but no natives folder in the last version

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've got Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

I loaded LWJGL3, the latest version 3.1.2. I've added it (like [here](http://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install#eclipse)) to a test project (Hello World from *lwjgl.org/guide*) and it works without setting anything (...like natives...).

Then i added Sling2D (like [here](http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_Slick2D_with_Eclipse)) except for setting the *Natives Library Location* because in the latest version of lwjgl3 there is no `natives` folder with `native<OS>.dll` files! It's only 1 folder with only `.jar` files.

If i run the Hello World test project (from [here](http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Hello_World)) I got the following error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path"

I read everywhere I have to set the *Natives Library Location* to the lwjgl/native folder with the OS-specific `.dll` files but i haven't this folder!

Comment: Update: I just loaded the older version lwjgl 2.9.3., there is a native folder, so i was setting the Natives Library Location and it works with Sling2D.
But how can i do it with lwjgl3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: You cant. Slick2D is made to work with lwjgl 2, lwjgl 3 however is way newer than Slick2D and therefore Slick2D does not support using lwjgl 3. I'd recommend you to use the newest 2.9.x version of lwjgl if you want to use Slick2D.

There might be a workaround though see: http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7095

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot! Well, since im new here I would be happy if u might upvote my Question. And sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Thanks, then mark the answer as valid, so others may find it useful tool :)